# Namespace declaration error in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I created a new module called `Album`. I added the following codes:
**`<AppName>/module/Album/Module.php`**:

```
 <?php

namespace Album;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface, ConfigProviderInterface
{
 public function getAutoloaderConfig()
 {
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
         __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
        ),
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
 }

 public function getConfig()
 {
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
 }
}
```

**`<AppName>/module/Album/config/module.config.php`**

```
<?php

return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
         ),
     ),

 'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'album' => array(
                 'type'    => 'segment',
                 'options' => array(
                     'route'    => '/album[/:action][/:id]',
                     'constraints' => array(
                         'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                         'id'     => '[0-9]*',
                     ),
                     'defaults' => array(
                         'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                         'action'     => 'index',
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
     ),



     'view_manager' => array(
         'template_path_stack' => array(
             'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),
 );
```

Then I refreshed my local server and got this error:

```
Fatal error: Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script in /var/www/html/trialone/module/Album/Module.php on line 3
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I see the whitespace at beginning of Module.php file

Comment: Uh oh... I removed it and it worked